# How to present language list along with proficiency

Tags: web-app, language

Our users can select a language from a drop-down list and proficiency levels, which are:

- **Speaking**

  - Not at all Proficient
  - Slightly Proficient
  - Moderately Proficient
  - Very Proficient
  - Extremely Proficient
- **Reading**

  - Not at all Proficient
  - Slightly Proficient
  - Moderately Proficient
  - Very Proficient
  - Extremely Proficient
- **Writing**

  - Not at all Proficient
  - Slightly Proficient
  - Moderately Proficient
  - Very Proficient
  - Extremely Proficient

and add it to their profile (same as in LinkedIn).

This is currently how we designed the layout for that section:
[image: language list]

To me this layout is confusing a bit. Is there a better way to show each language and its proficiency?

----- Clarification ------

Thanks 3nafish!

Good questions and sorry for being vague.

1. Yes, this profile will be visible to other users.
2. Once this panel is created it  will probably NOT be updated repeatedly.
3. For each language they must have the proficiency selected.
4. The language panel is informational only for HR users.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @MorVimmer! Can you clarify your constraints?  What specifically do you find problematic about the layout you show here?  Will this profile be made visible to other users? Is there a default? or is it important for users manually to select an option? Is the form likely to be set up once? or updated repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @DesignerAnalyst but using a colour / intensity gradient approach allows space for explanatory text, an aesthetically simpler UI (which according to [Nielsen heuristics](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) does matter). Appropriate scale will avoid color blindness issues.

Also the larger and simpler features are easier to scan. Which is probably valuable in supporting the likely user goals (e.g. Does this person have specific weaknesses in a language?  They Native speaker of which language(s)? )

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCGXvd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I like both solutions, especially Jayfang's. I agree with Jayfang. The user's goals is to quickly evaluate the skills of that person. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion that uses less words. This solution reduces clutter and makes comparison much more easy. You can use a tooltip to show the description of each symbol.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f34pN7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>